# Flex Datagrid event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid

Im using a Flex Advanced datgrid with five editable columns,
on focus the cursor is in first column and ready for editing,
now, i jus want to know how can i move to next column by pressing **ENTER** key [not by pressing Tab], is there any keyword for that???

HOpe this is clear
Thankxx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a keyUp event listener to the datagrid. In the event listener function check if the key pressed is the enter key. If it is, set the focus to the appropriate cell.